# Function returns 0x0 table

Tags: r, for-loop, google-earth

I have a function to compute latitude and longitude points in order to create a "ring" around a center location.   The problem is that the results print to the screen but are not stored anywhere.  My function creates a dataframe with 0 columns and 0 rows.  I want to be able to take these coordinates and use them elsewhere.  I would like to be able to nest this function as well, but I can't really nest it when it doesn't return anything.

My end goal is to create kml code.  I already have the kml code but need to repeat it many times.  The kml code creates  radius rings, fills them with color, and adds a name for the place.  I want to generate the files automatically by using a list of locations in lat/lon.

My question is, how can I get this function to return the list of coordinates that I want so that I may paste them in the kml code accordingly?  I can get it to loop using adply and get printed results for the 3 coordinates, but nothing is created.

I am also quite new to coding, please be gentle.  Thanks in advance.

```
make.ring.file=function(dist,df)
{

  R = 6378.14 #Radius of the Earth
  d = dist*1.609344 #Distance of ring radius in km
  lat1 = df$lat*(pi/180) #Current lat point converted to radians
  lon1 = df$lon*(pi/180) #Current lon point converted to radians
  num3=0
  index=seq(from=0,to=360,by=120)
  bear=NULL
  lat=NULL
  lon=NULL
  z=NULL
  coordlist=NULL
    for(n in 1:length(index))
    {
      bear[n]=index[n]*(pi/180)
      lat[n]=(asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(bear[n])))*(180/pi)
      lon[n]=(lon1 + atan2(sin(bear[n])*sin(d/R)*cos(lat1),
                         cos(d/R)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat[n]*(pi/180))))*(180/pi)
      z[n]=0
     coordlist[n]=paste(lon[n],lat[n],z[n],sep=",")  
    }  
     return(data.frame(cat(coordlist,"\n","\n")))

}

> head(x1)
       lat       lon
1 38.86095 -86.51672
2 30.63275 -84.41614
3 31.53697 -87.88780

> results=adply(x1,1,make.ring.file,dist=30)
-86.51672,39.2946592897837,0 -86.0358241901732,38.6431079084023,0 -86.9976158098268,38.6431079084023,0 -86.51672,39.2946592897837,0 

-84.41614,31.0664592897837,0 -83.9805971533182,30.4151694949636,0 -84.8516828466818,30.4151694949636,0 -84.41614,31.0664592897837,0 

-87.8878,31.9706792897837,0 -87.4481292235866,31.3193631233201,0 -88.3274707764134,31.3193631233201,0 -87.8878,31.9706792897837,0 

> str(results)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  0 variables

> is.data.frame(results)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: remove the cat function in your output - it prints to screen, rather than making what you want.

Comment: Removing the cat function returns a dataframe with a new column for each iteration.  The output I want is to have a long concatenated character string for the coordinates generated.  How can I do that?

Comment: I need the output to be something like this "-86.51672,39.2946592897837,0 -86.0358241901732,38.6431079084023,0 -86.9976158098268,38.6431079084023,0 -86.51672,39.2946592897837,0"  Just one long character string, stored somewhere.

Comment: I want to take the output and paste it as a character string in one row of another dataframe that has one column.  Each row of that dataframe is a line of kml code.  I want to paste these coordinates as a string in one row so that I can write it to a .kml file.  Which I can then load up in google earth.  If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
make.ring.file=function(dist,df)
{

    R = 6378.14 #Radius of the Earth
    d = dist*1.609344 #Distance of ring radius in km
    lat1 = df$lat*(pi/180) #Current lat point converted to radians
    lon1 = df$lon*(pi/180) #Current lon point converted to radians
    num3=0
    index=seq(from=0,to=360,by=120)
    bear=NULL
    lat=NULL
    lon=NULL
    z=NULL
    coordlist=NULL
    for(n in 1:length(index))
    {
        bear[n]=index[n]*(pi/180)
        lat[n]=(asin(sin(lat1)*cos(d/R) + cos(lat1)*sin(d/R)*cos(bear[n])))*(180/pi)
        lon[n]=(lon1 + atan2(sin(bear[n])*sin(d/R)*cos(lat1),
                             cos(d/R)-sin(lat1)*sin(lat[n]*(pi/180))))*(180/pi)
        z[n]=0
        coordlist[n]=paste(lon[n],lat[n],z[n],sep=",")  
    }  
    return(data.frame(out=paste(coordlist,collapse=" ")))

}
```

The key addition is:

```
return(data.frame(out=paste(coordlist,collapse=" ")))
```

The function `cat`, prints to console, so you can't assign it to anything - you were merely making an empty data.frame and printing.

The paste command works by pasting together the 4 lines of `coordlist`, with a separator of " ".  You can modify this as required for your downstream code.

Comment: That works great!  Thank you!  And thank you for the explanation on cat.  I liked using it to see what the output would look like that I wanted, but it just doesn't produce an output.